# Correct way to use MySQLi_* functions wiht ADOdb

Tags: php, mysqli, adodb

I have a question about usage of MySQLi_* functions in combination with ADOdb connection. Hope someone can provide additional input since I cannot find proper resources explaining this particular subject.

So I have an ADODB connection like this:

```
define('DBHOST', 'db_host');
define('DBUSER', 'db_user'); 
define('DBPASS', 'db_pass');    
define('DBNAME', 'db_name'); 

include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
$db = ADONewConnection('mysqli');
$db->Connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME) or die("Database not found!");
```

Let's now take a function like `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

I have found several sources where it is suggested to use it like this:

`$var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $var);`

However, this does not echo anything for `echo $var1;`. I suppose it is not the correct way to do it when having ADOdb as underlying interface.

So I tried another thing, which I saw in one of the ADOdb integrated functions:

`$var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->_connectionID, $var);`

Doing it this way, I can successfully echo `$var1`.

My question it, is this the correct way to do it?

Why should I use `$db->_connectionID`?

Does this approach apply to other MySQLi functions like `mysqli_insert_id()`, `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_select_db()` or I can use them as `($db, $var);`

Comment: `$var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($var);
echo $var1;` does not output anything... I have also done trough the suggested documentation and since the examples there are only related to regular mysqli connections, they cannot be applied in my case. Therefore, I need some advice on how to properly use those functions in combination with ADODB.

Comment: @user3132858 as outlined in your other question/answer. `mysqli_` requires db connection be passed to functions that require it, Unlike `mysql_`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you are right probably in the case when regular mysqli connection is used. However, I am asking why in my case `$var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $var)`; echo ($var1);` does not output anything?

Comment: *"$var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->_connectionID, $var);

Doing it this way, I can successfully echo $var1"* - what I wrote was an example, but you say you can echo that. What am I not grasping?

Comment: if I do `($db->_connectionID, $var)` I can echo `$var1` but if I do `($db, $var)` as suggested by official documentation and by you, I cannot echo `$var1`. So I am asking why the official way does not work with in my case and I should use `$db->_connectionID` instead?

Comment: again, that was just an example. the first parameter is the connection, being whatever connection var/method you're using.

Comment: so, question answered? everything's cleared up?

Comment: if what I said in comments answered the question, you can delete it. Otherwise, your question will remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thanks for trying to help, I understand that you used an example but I need to know why your example does not work in my particular case. Probably because of the connection var/method you mentioned, however the exact reason is still not clear...

Comment: my example and is also PHP.net's "example" did not work for you because of how you are using Adobe's connection method of `$db->_connectionID` --- `$connection` and `$db->_connectionID` both translate to being the "connection" parameter. It's up to you to decide "how" you want to use it, provided from the source's "method". I honestly don't know how else I can put it here in order for you to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing metaphors, so to speak.  The whole point of ADODB is to provide an abstract interface to many underlying database engines. In this case, ADODB is abstracting mysqli. Why then would you need to use mysqli functions directly?

The answer here is to use ADODB's ecaping mechanism, which in turn will abstract the database and use the corresponding mysqli functions internally.

```
$var1 = $db->qstr($var);
```

By changing just your connection setup, you could even switch to another database engine, unrelated to Mysql, without ever needing to change the above line.